# PhpStorm HTTP client

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

PhpStorm has built-in HTTP Client (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/http-client-in-product-code-editor.html), with JS support, which allows for writing tests. This is really handy, but would be even better, if we had a way to run those tests apart from PhpStorm, in CI environment or in console.

Is the any way to run them separately, or any script/library than accepts same syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible now.

I just built an open-source CLI application that support execute your existing http request files.

You can download the tool from: https://github.com/quangson91/intellij_rest_cli

Usage:

```
java -jar /path/to/restcli-1.0.jar -e "test" -s get-requests.http
```

This tool support:

- Execute Intellij HTTP request files.
- Running test script inside request files.
- Loading and inject environment variables from

  - http-client.env.json
  - http-client.private.env.json
- Cross platform: Windows, macOS, and Linux ready.
- Generate test report - JUnit format.  So you can show test report in the CI system.

[image: demo show test report on CI system]

Answer (score 2):

Not currently possible.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-239345 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified with any progress.